# Laravel Homestead error with nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, homestead

Found the error " 502 Bad Gateway
             nginx/1.9.9  " 
While checking server in laravel Homestead using the address: http://phpmyadmin.app:8000/

Whats the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: We need more info to help you. What do you see when you got o http://192.168.10.10:8000 if you browser?

Comment: Actually i am installing Homestead for Laravel. Now i am trying to install Phpmyadmin. After this command: sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin, i was trying to check my server and finding the error above :(

Comment: post your Homestead.yaml and hosts file

Comment: Host file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15265633/

Homestead file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15265637/

Please help me regarding the issue

Comment: I successfully installed Homestead then i tried to go to homestead machine following the directory vagrant@homestead:  $www 
 I have installed phpMyAdmin in www directory and mapped homestead.yaml file and also changed the hosts file. After that I tried to browse phpmyadmin.app:8000 but the error "502  Bad Gateway nginx/1.9.9" is showing. My 
Host file: paste.ubuntu.com/15265633 and Homestead.yaml file: paste.ubuntu.com/15265637 . Please feel free to ask for further queries.

Comment: I have a same problem. But other php projects are working well. Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your ip is not set to `192.168.10.10` then its possible you get the error also you might need to edit your homestead.yaml site configuration to `phpmyadmin.ap` and not `phpmyadmin.app` also refrain yourself from using `phpmyadmin.test`, `phpmyadmin.dev` and so on I do not know if its a bug homestead are yet to fix.

Hope this solve the issue.